# TinyOS UDP support?

Tags: networking, udp, network-protocols, udpclient, tinyos

Does TinyOS provide support for the UDP protocol ?

We are trying to create an IP Phone using a Micro-controller and were thinking of installing TinyOS on it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyOS has an IP stack (6lowPan) called BLIP which supports UDP and TCP although I have never used BLIP personally. See the link [HERE](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/BLIP_Tutorial) for more information. A good point to start would be to look at the UDP-echo application in apps folder of the TinyOS distribution.